# Is there a way to make dired buffers created by lists behave more like traditional dired?

Tags: dired

For example, when doing:

```
(dired '("custom-buffer" "~/.emacs.d" "/Volumes" "~/.bash_profile"))
```

I cannot sort, and when changing a name of a file it will not reappear in the buffer. An additional quirk is if I do `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` on `/Volumes` dired thinks I'm in the `~/.emacs.d` and will not open `/Volumes`. I know in the docs it says the sorting behavior will not work as expected.

So I suppose I'm just asking if there is a package or something that just makes it so I can list a bunch of files and all the usual dired commands working as expected. Or is there a better way of dealing with an arbitrary group of files? The main feature I would like the most I suppose is sorting.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about such things. Essentially, you're giving Dired a listing such as some `ls

Answer (score 1):

> so I can list a bunch of files and all the usual dired commands working as expected. Or is there a better way of dealing with an arbitrary group of files? The main feature I would like the most I suppose is sorting.

Good question. I don't think there's anything you can do about such things.

Essentially, you're giving Dired a listing such as some `ls` might provide. Dired has no way of generating such a listing, and it knows nothing about it. Sorting etc. are handled by the `ls` program (the listing generator).

(I'm just happy that Dired will at least let me create such a listing, with directories and files from anywhere. That's pretty good, even if you can't do some `ls`-related things with it.)

Comment: Ah thank you for the answer. Seems like I'll have to do my own tinkering.